# Conduit parser is interrupted prematurely

Tags: haskell, conduit, attoparsec

I'm working on a program where I need to parse data from a USB connection and write it to a circular buffer.

The issue I keep running into is that the parser is not consuming the input. Do I need to use another operator to connect the parser conduit to the stream of `ByteString`s?

If I remove the two 'filters' `dropC` and `dropWhileC`, the parser consumes some of the input but fails, because the first few chunks of data are junk.

Clearly my mental model of how the library works is off somehow (I've never used it before).

I'd also like to know if empty strings are treated as EOF markers by `conduitParser`, as with `attoparsec`s own [`parseWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.2.0/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString-Char8.html#v:parseWith).

```
-- |
sourcePort :: SerialPort -> Producer IO ByteString
sourcePort port = repeatMC (recv port 16)


-- |
parseSerialStream :: (Vector v (Int, Int)) => RingBuffer v (Int, Int) -> SerialPort -> IO () -- ConduitM a c IO ()
parseSerialStream buffer port = sourcePort port
                             .| dropC 4
                             .| dropWhileC B.null
                             .| conduitParser (parseMeasurement <* endOfLine)
                             $$ mapM_C (\item -> print item >> RB.append (snd item) buffer)
```

Comment: Does `sourcePort port .| dropC 4 >> dropWhileC B.null >>  conduitParser (parseMeasurement <* endOfLine) $$ .....` work?

Comment: Unfortunately not: `Couldn't match type \`ByteString' with \`()'`

Comment: How about with parentheses, like `sourcePort port .| (dropC 4 >> dropWhileC B.null >> conduitParser (parseMeasurement <* endOfLine)) $$ ..... `

Comment: Yeah, that *does* work, Thank you!

Comment: @danidiaz Would you like to write an answer explaining where I went wrong?

Comment: It is explained in this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10836477/1364288 Basically, `dropC` and `dropWhileC` are `Consumer`s, a more polymorphic form of `Sink`s which can also be used as `Conduit`s. The thing is that, by themselves, they just stop after dropping the specified elements, and terminate the stream. If you want to "keep doing something with the stream", for example parse it, you have to use monadic composition. When you composed the `drop`'s and `conduitParser` using `.|`, you made the parser wait for elements which never would arrive, because `drop`s never yield anything.

Comment: `conduit`, `pipes` and `streaming` all handle `drop` differently. In `pipes`, `drop` returns an intermediate `Pipe` stage which (unlike conduit's `drop`) does yield the rest of the stream automatically http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.4/docs/Pipes-Prelude.html#v:drop And in `streaming`, `drop` returns a function from `Stream` to `Stream`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.1.4.5/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:drop

Comment: @danidiaz One final question: it seems to me like dropping some items from a list and feeding the remainder to another conduit should be a fairly common use-case. Do you happen to know if I could rewrite my function more elegantly with other operators (apart from wrapping `dropC` like @MichaelSnoyman showed)?

Comment: That I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@danidiaz has explained in the comments that `dropC` et.al. do not yield any values, which is why you must use monadic composition instead of piping (`.|`).

To anyone who stumbles upon this question, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10836477/1364288) for details.

This code works as expected:

```hs
parseSerialStream :: RingBuffer VU.Vector (Int, Int) -> SerialPort -> IO () -- ConduitM a c IO ()
parseSerialStream buffer port = sourcePort port
                             .| (dropC 4
                             >> dropWhileC B.null
                             >> conduitParser (parseMeasurement <* endOfLine))
                             $$ mapM_C (\item -> RB.append (snd item) buffer)
```

I liked how the pipes looked though. Oh well...